# Identifying missing small part Campagnolo brake lever

Tags: vintage, brake-levers, campagnolo

I'm missing a small part that guides the brake cable in my Campagnolo brake lever. Any idea how to find one of these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Update: This is what the part looks like (taken from the other lever)
[image][image]*

Comment: Do you have the opposite brake lever?  If it has the same part, then a photo of that may help.

Comment: Have you tried the Campagnolo website? They have spare parts catalogs that go back to at least 90s.

Comment: @Criggie that's a really good idea! photos added

Comment: @ojs I can't find this on the website and to be honest - I'm not sure what groupset these are from. They appear to be super record 7-speed from the late 80s / early 90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a "cable guide plate"
Part number 7283057 in the picture below
Searching for "campagnolo brake cable guide plate" will turn up results.

[image]

Comment: Great find!  Its definitely nothing like a common Shimano lever.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally buying the part would be easiest, but finding the part to buy could be a whole lot of work.  Identifying a part number is your first task there.

If I was in this position, I'd try two solutions:

1. Find a piece of aluminium or brass and carve it out.

You could start with pipe with the same radius and cut out a sector, or a block of metal and do a lot of filing on the parts that matter.  Doubtless there are parts that don't have to match perfectly.

If you had access to a press it may be possible to form some of this shape, but you'd have to have some kind of buck or dies to push it appropriately.  Might not be worth it for a one-off.   Perhaps a hammer-formed shape will give you enough of the curve that the outside can be made at a bench-grinder.

---

2. Depending what kind of tension the cable is under, you may also get away with a 3d printed replacement part though I'd worry that the groove will be eroded over time.